# No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtwebengine

**I'm using windows**

> pip install PyQt5

> pip install PyQtWebEngine

I've installed the web engine still it's showing the error

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('http://google.com'))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.showMaximized()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QApplication.setApplicationName('Pheonix Browser')
window = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

[image: Error Screen SS]

Comment: I believe it is `from PyQt5 import PyQtWebEngine`

Comment: **tried it.**

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OM\PycharmProjects\Pheonix_Browser\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import PyQtWebEngine
ImportError: cannot import name 'PyQtWebEngine' from 'PyQt5' (C:\Users\OM\PycharmProjects\Pheonix_Browser\venv\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\__init__.py)`

Comment: it's `QtWebEngine`  drop the `Py` ... `from PyQt5.QtWebEngine import *`

Comment: still the same issue :(

Comment: `QtWebEngine` doesn't contain the *widgets*, but only the core library, `PyQtWebEngineWidgets` is not a valid module. It's `from PyQt5 QtWebEngineWidgets import *`. If it still doesn't work, tell us how you installed it, and report the environment you're using, including Qt/Python/OS versions.

Comment: still same issue.           **python 3.9     pip 22.0.4(latest)     PyQt5 (12.10.1)    Windows 10 Pro**

Comment: Do you know if you are in an active virtual env when you run pip install? you would see (env) at the beginning of the command line. if so, the packages are installing into this rather than global, which is fine, you just need to ensure to activate the env before running python.

Comment: @AhmadKhan Most likely you have installed QtWebEngine in one python but pycharm used another (possibly a virtualenv). The import is correct.

Comment: be sure that the various modules have the same version, try `pip list` -> `PyQt6                             6.1.1; PyQt6-WebEngine 6.3.0; PyQt6-WebEngine-Qt6 6.3.0` in this case the versions are different and `PyQt6` needs an update, `pip install -U PyQt6`

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
import PyQtWebEngine
```

Instead of using,

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
```